# DIST strings - Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: monte-carlo

I recently read something that talks about DIST distribution strings.  It appears to be a way to take a long string of previously generated numbers and somehow compress them into a string that can then be used by others.  I believe it's lossy.  I'm having a great deal of trouble finding out anything other than some generalities about it.  It may be proprietary, I don't know.

Does anyone know where I might be able to find something out about the algorithm used to create such a DIST string?  Also if anyone knows anything about this, is this something that's being used anywhere and how useful does it appear to be?

Answer (score 1):

Online, there doesn't seem to be much information, although it's supposedly described by its inventor, Sam Savage, in its book *The Flaw of Averages*.

Apparently, it's a lossy XML standard, according to [this website](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DistributionString). It looks like a proprietary standard managed by [Vector Economics](http://vectoreconomics.com/content/content/what-distribution-string-dist) and [Probability Management](http://www.probabilitymanagement.org/). If this standard is a key piece of intellectual property for Sam Savage, I doubt the standard is publicized anywhere.

It appears to be used in the financial services industry, but for scientific purposes, the lack of openness may be a big problem when it comes to checking numerical results.